# Doctrine - Unknown column type "mystoragetype" requested

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi i am just getting error when i tried to update doctrine scheme in my Symphony App.
I run

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and getting error this error

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                                                                                     
Unknown column type "mystoragetype" requested.
Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType().
You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypeMap().
If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type.
Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes().
If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

I couldn't find anything related to "mystoragetype" in my project and also tried to add type but nothing happened.
Could you figure it out why i am getting this error?

Comment: can you update your question with your entity

Comment: Which entity do you want? I have 18 but doesn't find 'mystoragetype' in any of them

Comment: run : grep -ri "mystoragetype" . (<- dont forget the dot ".") from the same place you run php app/console. There must be some entity with this type, then just get rid of it or implement this type in Doctrine

Comment: It didn't find anything

Comment: didn't work, still same error unfortunately

Comment: You must have any entity or mapping file which defines the `mystoragetype` for a column. Maybe some third party library or bundle  uses it. For the solution you'll need to register the custom type in Symfony to recognize it (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types)

Comment: I have same issue. And I don't have any `mystoragetype` in my code. But I have this into comments in my database columns.

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine adds comments to fields with custom type: Something like:(DC2Type:mystoragetype). I think you generated schema with that type and had to remove type from entity. But comment remains in database.

Comment: For me this worked:
1. Delete all comments from DB where the (DC2Type:mystoragetype) appeared. <br/>
2. Clear cache: app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Answer (score -1):

Add to your migration only the raw SQL query that will delete the colum comments, e.g.

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE some_table CHANGE COLUMN problematic_column problematic_column COLUMN_TYPE AFTER some_other_column');
```

Or if you want to get rid of the whole table (if you don't need it anymore):

```php
$this->addSql('DROP TABLE some_table');
```

Doctrine is loading schema lazily. If you will not use any of the schema methods (e.g. `$schema->dropTable`) inside migrations, Doctrine will not check the schema and will not find out that there is some problem with missing type.

Comment: Please share more details. How could dropping any table resolve the given error message? Also, are there possible any consequences on dropping a table? Like: data loss?

Comment: @NicoHaase Deleting table is an *example*, I have explained it more. The author of the question does not specify whats the problem with the schema. 
I had the same error as it is mentioned here when I was trying to delete unneeded table so I shared my solution.
The problem is that Doctrine can't find custom Type that is specified in the column. There are only 2 solutions for this problem: delete the reference in the column comment (by modifying column, deleting column or deleting unneeded table) or creating the missing type in PHP code.